# Place icon left of the text in treeview column using Python and GTK3

Tags: python, treeview, gtk, icons, gtk3

I'm using this code to add icons to the TreeView column:

```py
 def build_tree_view(self):
    self.explorer_store = Gtk.TreeStore(Pixbuf, str, str)
    icon = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().load_icon("folder", 22, 0)
    for connname, conndata in self.config.get('connections', {}).items():
        parent = self.explorer_store.append(None, [icon, connname, self.get_dsn(conndata)])
    self.tree_view = Gtk.TreeView(self.explorer_store)

    renderer_pixbuf = Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf()
    renderer_text = Gtk.CellRendererText()

    column1 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Column", renderer_text)

    column1.pack_start(renderer_text, True)
    column1.pack_start(renderer_pixbuf, False)

    column1.add_attribute(renderer_pixbuf, "pixbuf", 0)
    column1.add_attribute(renderer_text, "text", 1)
    self.tree_view.append_column(column1)
```

And I got this result:

[image: TreeView]

How can I align icons to the left of the text?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution! When I create a column I do not need to pass renderer as a second parameter:

```
column1 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Column", renderer_text)
```

The correct code is:

```
column1 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Column")
```